# Minecraft baby zombie riding a zombie villager

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

[image]

So I was going down to my lab I made and I saw a baby zombie riding a zombie villager.  Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 4):

According to the [Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Zombie#Baby_zombies) for the PE edition of the game:

> On the Pocket Edition, they can ride other passive mobs, as well as other zombies and spiders.

This appears to be normal behavior.

Comment: This is a feature of the Bedrock Edition, which is the version of PE, and Console Editions of the game.

Comment: This feature scares me. Zombie calvary of baby zombies riding tall zombies? Lethal and creepy.

Answer (score 0):

In Minecraft mobs can spawn on top of one another and are able to stack or "ride" each other. If i remember correctly, by killing the mob on the bottom of the stack, the mobs on top of it will be released and will behave normally.